# Mock Oracle Procedure in H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, h2

I have the below repository calling Oracle database. Oracle has IN parameter and REF_CURSOR as OUT parameter.Can I create a similar SP in H2 database and run my below  `RepoClass`class against the SP created in H2 database rather than calling actual Oracle DB

```
@Repository
public class RepoClass {

    
    
    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcCallFactory simpleJdbcCallFactory;
    


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Data> getData(Data d) {
        
        

        
        
          Map<String, Object> result =
                  simpleJdbcCallFactory.getSimpleJdbc()
                  .execute(
                  d.getDate()
                  
                   );
          
          
          
          return (List<Data>) result.get("p_ref_cur_result_set");
      }
}
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with junit/mockito/spring-boot and even java, right? It's about rewriting the SP in H2?

Comment: yes but not necessarily .i just want to how to test the DAO layer effectively